# SQLite3 database or disk is full on csv imports

Tags: sqlite

This issue has been discussed on a number of threads, but none of the proposals seem to apply to my case.

I have a very large sqlite database (4Tb). I am trying to import csv files from the terminal

```
sqlite3 -csv -separator "       " /data/mydb.db ".import '|cat *.csv' mytable"
```

I intermittently receive **SQLite3 database or disk is full** errors. Re-running the command after an error usually succeeds.

Some notes:

1. /data has 3.2Tb free
2. /tmp  has 1.8Tb free.
3. *.csv takes up approximately 802Gb.
4. Both /tmp and /data are using ext4 which has a maximum file size of 16tb.
5. The only process accessing the database is the one mentioned above.
6. PRAGMA integrity_check returns ok.
7. Test on both
   -sqlite3 --version - **3.38.1 2022-03-12 13:37:29 38c210fdd258658321c85ec9c01a072fda3ada94540e3239d29b34dc547a8cbc** and **3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54 3bfa9cc97da10598521b342961df8f5f68c7388fa117345eeb516eaa837balt1**
8. OS - Ubuntu 20.04

Any thoughts on what could be happening?

(Unless there is an informed reason for why I am exceeding the limits sqlite, I would prefer to avoid suggestions that I move to a client/server RDBMS.)

Comment: `sqlite3 --version` ?

Comment: i would experiment with  `-cmd "PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL"` and OFF (instead of WAL) and see if it still happens =/

Comment: maybe an `strace sqlite3 -csv ...` could tell us what is going on, it wouldn't surprise me if there's a write() that actually fails somewhere, causing sqlite to return disk full error, would be interesting to see (and would shift the blame from sqlite to your filesystem)

Comment: Thanks will try all of your suggestions

Comment: any luck with WAL?

Comment: The process is busy running - it takes a long time to run but so far no issues.

Comment: ```PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL``` just displayed the error after 22hrs. It left a 368Gb WAL file. I'll try your strace suggestion but it might take days until I get an answer.

Comment: warning, don't delete the WAL file manually, the right way to delete the WAL file is ```sqlite3 -cmd "PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE" foo.db3 "PRAGMA journal_mode;"``` - running that command should clean up the WAL file correctly.. is importing the files in chunks an option? eg would you be comfortable with running a ```BEGIN TRANSACTION;COMMIT;``` for every 100k csv fields or so? or do you need all 800gb of csv files committed in a single transaction?

Comment: I ran vacuum and it broke with the same error - sadly, everything in the wal file was lost. I'm testing with smaller chunks but I would really like to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thought I would post a quick update. I could never get my database larger than 4Tb. In my case, I was able to partition the database into 1Tb chunks and use attach/union all in my queries.

In any case, the documentation doesn't recommend databases larger than 1Tb so it's not surprising that things get unstable when you do.

Comment: i would love to see a `strace sqlite3 -csv ...stuff... | tail -c 9999999 | tee trace.log` log from when it fails, but totally understand if you don't want to run it for hours/days just to research the failure ^^ (EDIT: originally i posted `head -c` instead of `tail -c`, that was a mistake, i definitely mean `tail -c`)

Comment: Definitely days on my slow drive - I have a spare machine - I'll set it up to run strace and update you.

Comment: It took less time than I expected: https://pastebin.com/idgnDmEU  - lightly edited it to remove private information.

Comment: thanks! my first guess is that it read *something* in that newfstatat command that it didn't like, and terminated, but i should re-read it when i have time to think about it (i g2g now)

Comment: what do you get from `df -h .`  in the directory you ran sqlite3? and what do you get from `cat /proc/mounts`  ?

Comment: `df -h .` `Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3        15T   13T  1.5T  90% /`

Comment: `cat /proc/mounts` returns a bunch of results including docker overlays. Here is the line for /def/sda3: `/dev/sda3 / ext4 rw,relatime 0 0`. Let me know if you need to see any other lines

Comment: what do you get from `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda3` ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RZEKQQ6U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't figure it out, but [someone else did](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/6e286c968aa0b93949c4520d1e0b62105963cc0824147c6ced763d9a0586d9d2), am pretty sure this will "fix it" until you reach 8TB-ish:

> sqlite3 ... "PRAGMA main.max_page_count=2147483647; .import '|cat *.csv' mytable"

However the invocation

> sqlite3 ... "PRAGMA main.journal_mode=DELETE; PRAGMA main.max_page_count; PRAGMA main.max_page_count=2147483647; PRAGMA main.page_size=65536;VACUUM; import '|cat *.csv' mytable;"

should allow the db to grow to ~200TB, but that VACUUM command, which is needed to apply the new page_size, requires a lot of free space to run, and will probably use a long time =/

good news is that you only need to run that once and it should be a permanent change to your db, your next invocation only needs `sqlite3 ... "import '|cat *.csv' mytable;"`

notably, this will probably break again around ~200TB

Comment: Thanks for the sleuthing. I've increased the number of pages as per your first suggestion - I expect that it will still run for a long time but the database has now exceeded the previous 4tb limit.

Comment: @AdiEyal its also cool that you're pushing SQLite close to its limits ^^ (it's default limits at least), cheers

Comment: Despite the insistence by many on Stack Overflow that you need a "real" database if you're working at scale - my 1tb databases are performant and are perfect for my use case.